# How to delete a job from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, object-detection

I tried creating a new job on GCP. The status of the job is displayed as on queue.

However, when I run the following command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs describe object_detection_188001
```

It shows an error as shown below:

```
createTime: '2017-12-18T07:53:42Z'
endTime: '2017-12-18T07:59:15Z'
errorMessage: "The replica ps 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason:\
  \ Error. \nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\"\
  , line 174, in _run_module_as_main\n    \"__main__\", fname, loader, pkg_name)\n\
  \  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in\
  \ run_globals\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py\"\
  , line 49, in <module>\n    from object_detection import trainer\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py\"\
  , line 27, in <module>\n    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder\n\
  \  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py\"\
  , line 21, in <module>\n    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2\n\
  ImportError: cannot import name preprocessor_pb2\n\nThe replica ps 1 exited with\
  \ a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. \nTraceback (most recent call\
  \ last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 174, in _run_module_as_main\n\
  \    \"__main__\", fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\"\
  , line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py\"\
  , line 49, in <module>\n    from object_detection import trainer\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py\"\
  , line 27, in <module>\n    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder\n\
  \  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py\"\
  , line 21, in <module>\n    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2\n\
  ImportError: cannot import name preprocessor_pb2\n\nThe replica ps 2 exited with\
  \ a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error. \nTraceback (most recent call\
  \ last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 174, in _run_module_as_main\n\
  \    \"__main__\", fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\"\
  , line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py\"\
  , line 49, in <module>\n    from object_detection import trainer\n  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py\"\
  , line 27, in <module>\n    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder\n\
  \  File \"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py\"\
  , line 21, in <module>\n    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2\n\
  ImportError: cannot import name preprocessor_pb2\n\nTo find out more about why your\
  \ job exited please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=626904481388&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fobject_detection_188001&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22object_detection_188001%22"
etag: Rp0MpFoEOCo=
jobId: object_detection_188001
startTime: '2017-12-18T07:58:45Z'
state: FAILED
trainingInput:
  args:
  - --train_dir=gs://weeddetection/train
  - --pipeline_config_path=gs://weeddetection/data/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
  jobDir: gs://weeddetection/train
  masterType: standard_gpu
  packageUris:
  - gs://weeddetection/train/packages/3ec30d866964baa26dd523360aed8221aa24ebaa4c527d34bf10fedbf2baf456/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz
  - gs://weeddetection/train/packages/3ec30d866964baa26dd523360aed8221aa24ebaa4c527d34bf10fedbf2baf456/slim-0.1.tar.gz
  parameterServerCount: '3'
  parameterServerType: standard
  pythonModule: object_detection.train
  region: us-central1
  runtimeVersion: '1.2'
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  workerCount: '5'
  workerType: standard_gpu
trainingOutput:
  consumedMLUnits: 2.76
```

Is there a way to fix this error? I googled and found a fix from the following link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2739

But, now when I try to create a new job it shows that I have exceeded the quota.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota failure for project eco-serenity-188001. The requested 16.536900000000003 ML Units exceed the allowed maximum of 15. To read more about Cloud ML Engine quota, see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas.
```

Is there a way to delete the existing job?

Comment: I was having the same trouble, this link can help someone: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/delete